# String to double, precision lost

Tags: iphone, ios, double, nslog

I have 53.025709438664 in string when I do `[string_variable doubleValue]`,  I get 53.025709.
I use `NSLog(@"%f")` to print it.

How I can get full precision value ?

Comment: why don't you use long double or long long data type?

Comment: thanks, but double have enough precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the format specifiers provided in [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

You cannot get all the digits after decimal point.

**Edit:**
If you know exact number of digits after decimal, then we could use something as follows

```
NSString *s  = @" 53.025709438664";
double d = [s doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%.12f",d);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I thought that doubleValue cut this, now i know i was wrong.